# Recursive Function Call in Ruby Got Error: wrong number of arguments (3 in 1)

Tags: ruby, function, recursion, arguments, call

I am trying to write a recursive function to create a binary tree, which, if has leaves, then the left leaf is devided by 1.5, and the rught leaf is multiply 1.5. I wrote the following statements:

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :left
    attr_accessor :right
    attr_accessor :data
    def initialize(x=nil)
       @left = nil
       @right = nil
       @data = x
    end
end
s = 100
u = 1.5
t = 4
def treeCreator(s=100,u=1.5,t=4)
    if t == 0
    then tree = Tree.new(s)
    else
        ltree = treeCreator(s/u,u,t-1)
        rtree = treeCreator(s*u,u,t-1)
        tree = Tree.new(s,ltree,rtree)
    end
end
treeCreator(100,1.5,4)
```

When I run the above program in Ruby (irb), I got the following error message:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
from (irb): 65: in 'initialize'
from (irb): 80: in 'new'
from (irb): 80: in 'treeCreator'
from (irb): 78: in 'treeCreator'
from (irb): 78: in 'treeCreator'
from (irb): 78: in 'treeCreator'
from (irb): 83
from '(main)'
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Ruby style avoids the use of the optional `then`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your initalize method to:

```
def initialize(data, left = nil, right = nil)
   @left, @right, @data = left, right, data
end
```

OTHER POINTS:

Those lines:

```
s = 100
u = 1.5
t = 4
```

do nothing. There should be no `then` after `if`. In ruby methods and variable should be written in snake_case by convention, hence your method should be `tree_creator`. Last line:

```
treeCreator(100,1.5,4)
```

can be written just as:

```
treeCreator
```

since you've set default params in method declaration.